# JclMapi - e-mail message window goes underneath the main form

Tags: delphi, mapi

I'm experiencing some troubles with JclMAPI. Currently I'm using JCL 2.6 Build 5178 with Delphi XE3.
The main form of my application is a MDIForm which handles different MDIChild forms. From one of these I can display a modal form and from it I call the `JclSimpleBringUpSendMailDialog` assigning the `ParentWND` parameter with the modal form handle.
Normally this method opens the email message window in front of the modal form. 
My problem is that sometimes the e-mail message window goes underneath the application mainForm and I'm not able to bring it to the front anymore. 
So the application waits for the return value of the Jcl Method and I'm not able to reactivate it. Real problem is that the e-mail window is behind my application and I can't compose the message.
i've had no luck on the internet searching.
Have you ever experienced this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to switch to using the Outlook Object Model instead of Simple MAPI. This way you can bring Outlook's main window to the foreground first before displaying the message. Outlook's HWND can be retrieved by casting the Explorer object (returned buy Application.ActiveExplorer) to IOleWindow and calling IOleWindow.GetWindow. Once you have HWND, you can bring it to the foreground using something like the folloowing:

```
function ForceForegroundWindow(hWnd: THandle): BOOL;
var
  hCurWnd: THandle;
begin
  hCurWnd := GetForegroundWindow;
  AttachThreadInput(
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurWnd, nil),
    GetCurrentThreadId, True);
  Result := SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
  AttachThreadInput(
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurWnd, nil),
    GetCurrentThreadId, False);
end;
```

Comment: I need to use JclMAPI Objects because I have to support both Outlook than Thunderbird.

Comment: You can still check if Outlook is installed and bring it to the foreground. There is no way to do what you need using Simple MAPI alone.

Comment: In the most of the cases JclMapi function "does its work": the new e-mail message window is displayed correctly in front of my application (even if Outlook or Thunderbird are closed) but sometimes it didn't. I can't tell exactly what are the right conditions that cause the problem because I'm not able to replicate the issue on my develop environment.
Using Outlook Object Model means change a big part of the mailing system of my application and I can't adopt this solution for now but I'll give it a try. If there will be no other solution I will use Outlook Object Model.

Comment: I think you are missing my point - you can use OOM to check if Outlook is already running and bring it to the foreground before invoking your Simple MAPI code.

Comment: Thank you Dimitry! After testing your solution I can now retrieve the Outlook Main Window Handle, force it to the foreground and link the message window directly to it.